Earth science dataset for binary classification
I'm a statistician looking for a dataset in earth science for a binary classification task, i.e., the response variable should be binary. My goal is to test a newly developed version of the invariant causal prediction algorithm, which tries to find the immediate causal drivers of some response variable. Do you have any suggestions for interesting datasets with roughly 3 to 10 covariates (continuous or categorical) and a binary response? Any help would be much appreciated!
